# Import only one columns from SQL dump file

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to import only one column in a single table from SQL dump file for MySQL?

Also is there a way to extract one table out using Unix command as the file I have is 18GB

What is the most efficient way to import only one column?

Comment: Please, provide example of data.

Comment: My sample data is too big. It's just an SQL file dumped using `mysqldump`

Comment: Example, only example.

Comment: using gui interface you can extract individual table into sql file too eg. navicat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MyDumpSplitter](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script) is a tool that uses Linux commands like `sed` to extract one table from a larger SQL dump file.

However, extracting one column from that table is harder, since the INSERT statements contain full rows.

Probably the easiest solution is to restore the one table (for instance to the `test` database), and then `SELECT` the one column you want out of it.